# How can I use multiple port numbers for an external FTP server in IIS 7?

Tags: windows-10, ftp, iis-7

So I know how to set up a basic FTP server in IIS 7, but I'm a little confused about ports. I believe I've had a few different FTP sites (each with their own directories) hosted on my desktop, each also with their own ports such as `:2100`, `:2101`, `:2102`, etc. Not too long after I started all of those sites, I started running into issues. When attempting to connect to one which wasn't my default :21 port (which led to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`), it would give me an error saying:

```
An error occurred opening that folder on the FTP server.
Make sure you have permission to access that folder.

Details:
200 Type set to A.
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,114,243,202).
```

This error ONLY occurred when connecting from an external network, not internally with other PC's on the same network. (It is still giving me the same error when trying to connect.)

Here's where I am now: I recently got an SSD as a replacement to my old HDD so I installed Windows again and started from scratch. The same thing is happening, and this is what I've gathered so far:

- Windows Defender Firewall has nothing to do with it since I turned it off completely and still got the error
- When changing the external port to some other number than `:21` (such as `:2121`), I was able to connect, so I'm thinking the issue must be in IIS
- My FTP client (whether it be Windows File Explorer or Google Chrome) requests a username and password (which means it is finding a connection rather than telling me that the destination server doesn't exist)

If anyone needs any further information, please feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTP performs data transfer through dedicated TCP connections on randomly-allocated ports. (In active mode the server connects back to the client; in passive mode the client connects to the server; but the general mechanism remains the same.)

Notice how the response to PASV ("Entering passive mode") includes the server's private IP address `192,168,0,114` as well as a port number `243,202` (i.e. 62410). Because your FTP server is behind a NAT router, the client won't be able to establish data connections for two reasons:

1. The address is private and therefore unreachable to the client. Of course, the client could just ignore this address and use the server's original address which it already knows for the main "control" connection (and indeed many FTP clients do exactly that for security reasons), but...
2. Your router doesn't know that connections to this temporary port should be *forwarded* to the FTP server, so it will just discard the packets leading to a timeout. (This would be a problem with firewalls even if NAT weren't present.)

So what's the difference between port 21 and port 2100? It's not in your FTP server, it's in your router.

When the control connection runs over standard FTP port 21, many routers actually *look inside* the connection, snoop on the PORT/PASV commands being sent over it, and dynamically add temporary port-forwarding rules every time the client needs a data connection. So whenever your router sees "227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,114,243,202)" from port 21, it creates a port-forwarding rule for WAN:62410 → 192.168.0.114:62410 and allows the data connection to be made.

In addition to that, many routers actually *rewrite* the IP address in PORT/PASV, changing the server's local address to the router's WAN address. So even though the server sends "227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,114,243,202)", the client magically receives "227 Entering Passive Mode (<WAN_IP>,243,202)".

All of this is done *only* on port 21, because then the router *knows* it's looking at an FTP control connection. It cannot just do the same magic on all ports, because it could misinterpret completely unrelated data (e.g. it could even misdetect this webpage if it weren't for HTTPS!). And of course it only works as long as the FTP control connection itself isn't encrypted using TLS/SSL.

The three things you can do (if you must continue using FTP at all) are:

1. Check whether IIS7 supports configuring a specific port range for inbound PASV connections. Enable this option in IIS *and* create a permanent port-forwarding rule in your router. For example, you could designate 64000–64999 as the PASV ports and then port-forward all of them to your FTP server. (The number of ports you need depends on how many concurrent transfers you plan on having, plus spares. Hopefully your router allows forwarding a whole range at once?)

   The advantage of this method is that it allows you to use TLS/SSL for the control connection. It's also a one-time configuration for all sites on the same server. (On the other hand, you have to rely on clients using the correct IP address, but practically most of them already do that.)
2. Alternatively, check whether your router supports configuring the FTP "ALG" (application-layer gateway) on additional ports besides 21. If it does, mark all your additional sites (:2100, :2101, etc.) as FTP ports.
3. If neither option works, you could set the FTP server to be the "DMZ host" on your router – which is like option 1 but configures port-forwarding for *all* ports on all protocols.

Comment: Thank you so much, I ended up going with the DMZ option because my router doesn't support ALG and as far as I can tell, I can't add a port range for PASV connections in IIS7, I could very possibly be wrong, but either way the last option also appealed to me because I had all protocols already port-forwarded in my router and I don't have a ton of FTP sites running, port-forwarding every one individually isn't much of a hassle. Thanks again!

Comment: [It definitely seems possible](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings-in-iis-7#step-1-configure-the-passive-port-range-for-the-ftp-service).